# Wireless Adapter needs periodic reset to connect to Home Group; Internet never affected (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking

I have a media pc (Windows 8) set up in my house with a server running on it.  This allows me to connect to it and modify things from a different PC in the house (rather than always having to walk over to the media PC).

Everything is great except that the connection to these other computers frequently drops out and I have to reset the wireless network adapter on the media pc for things to work again.  The strange thing is that the internet is always working on the media pc regardless of its ability to connect to other computers.

I am quite sure that the server is running on the media PC because I can always access the pages I want from the media PC, just not always from other pc's in the house.

Symptom: 
The ip for the media pc is, say, x.x.x.x.  After a reset, I can access pages on that ip from all pc's in the house.  After some time, I can only access those pages from the media pc.  Same with file sharing.  When connecting to the media PC fails, the log of the clients report "Connection refused".

- I have assigned a static ip to the media pc from within my router. 
  That didn't help.
- My media pc is not going to sleep at any point.
- My wireless adapter is up to date with the latest drivers.

Please help me debug why the wireless adapter needs resetting and whether I can prevent the problem altogether or somehow automatically get it to reset when needed.